# How to release the Content Completion menu in nvim without pressing Esc?

Tags: neovim, nvim.cmp

I'm using `hrsh7th/nvim-cmp` and some related packages to achieve content completion in `nvim`

However, in some cases which happen enough times, it becomes very cumbersome to use. Not sure if there's a proper way of doing this or not:

Assume you just typed a word/keyword in your favorite language and you're ready to press `ENTER` to start a new line. At this time, `nvim` shows you a dropdown of your choices. I don't want any of those! I'm happy with what I typed.

How can I start my new line without selecting anything from the dropdown menu?

Currently, I have to do either of these two:

1. press `ESC` to get rid of the menu. This works but removes me from the Editing mode. Then I have to press `o` to open a new line and start typing again
2. press `ENTER` selecting one of the items in the context menu. Then press `ESC` to exit editing mode. press `X` repeatedly to delete what was pasted. Then press `o` to start a new line!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it:

```
-    ["<CR>"] = cmp.mapping.confirm { select = true },
+    ["<CR>"] = cmp.mapping.confirm { select = false },
```

So now the default item won't be selected by me pressing `Enter`. If I wanted the top item I'd be doing a `Tab` prior to pressing `Enter`.